# Is this formula for energy fluctuation in Callen's Thermodynamics correct or missing a factor of 2?

Tags: thermodynamics, textbook-erratum

I am reading Thermodynamics and an Introduction to Thermostatistics, 2nd Edition,R. B. Callen,1985 (https://doi.org/10/c7sn3s )

According to my calculations, I think there should be a factor of 2 in the second term of equation 19.15, p.427.
Does anyone agree, or can prove me wrong?
Thanks.

Here's the equation in the book:
[image: Eq. 19.15, p.427]

My derivation of the same quantity is done by expanding:
$$
\begin{align}
\left\langle \left(\Delta E\right)^{2}\right\rangle &=-\left(\partial_{\beta}-\frac{P}{\beta}\partial_{P}\right)\overline{E}
 \\&=-\left(\partial_{\beta}-\frac{P}{\beta}\partial_{P}\right)\left(\partial_{\beta}-\frac{P}{\beta}\partial_{P}\right)\left(\beta F\right)
 \\&=-\left(\partial_{\beta}\overline{U}-2P\partial_{\beta}\overline{V}+\frac{P^{2}}{\beta}\partial_{P}\overline{V}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Where the macrostate probability is $p=e^{\beta(F-U)}$ and $U=E+PV$. After turning $\beta$ into $T$ I get exactly the same thing except for the aforementioned factor.

EDIT 1 : Since $d_{T}E\mid_{P}=d_{T}U\mid_{P}-Pd_{T}V$, it is as if the first term in the book's equation is the first term of this RHS and the second was not included.

EDIT 2 : I cross-checked by plugging a different formula for the same quantity that I found in p.344 of Statistical Physics - Part 1: Course of Theoretical Physics - (Vol. 5 LANDAU AND LIFSHITZ), ISBN: 978-81-8147-790-3:
[image: Landau's equation]
I get the same as in my derivation (after accounting for the $T\rightarrow k_BT$), so I am starting to think there is indeed an error in Callen's.